# Is it okay to point to your own website?

Tags: discussion

I've got a website that I frequently post woodworking projects, tips, and tricks to. On occasion I've felt the need to direct people to that site but have avoided doing so to avoid coming across as one of those annoying people who posts their web address in everyone else's forum. But, I'm wondering if it's okay to point to my own website. Is it considered "spam"?

Related to that, if I learn a new trick that I'm excited to share, am I allowed to A my own Q and link to my own website for full details?

Comment: The key is that linking to your own site should be ancillary. Answers should be able to stand on their own.

Comment: Also, it would be great (for us) to link from your blog back to your question/answer here!

Answer (score 3):

To answer your last question, yes you are allowed to answer your own questions, but be warned, people tend to judge them a little harsher.  Also As long as you have a good answer here, have a link to a much longer and in depth article (even your own) is just fine.

Do you have your site listed on your profile?

Comment: I do have my site listed in my WW profile (not sure about the others).

Answer (score 3):

> am I allowed to A my own Q

Here's an article about that:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Let me quote:

> To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is *explicitly encouraged***.

---

> link to my own website for full details

Sure, just like any other website. Mentioning that it's yours won't hurt.
The rule of thumb is that the answer should work without the link.

related: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 1):

To a large degree I think it depends on what the linked content is. If you're citing yourself as an authority on the subject matter, then you should actually be a somewhat well-respected and well-known authority.

If you're just linking to an article that objectively and illustrates a fact (e.g., "this is one way to cut a dovetail"), then I think it's fine.

As others mentioned, you are encouraged to ask and answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

The big problem with linking to personal blogs is ephemerality.  When you post a link to a blog, there is no guarantee that your blog will be there tomorrow.  As a result, you can have link rot in questions that link to random content, no matter how well-intentioned.

As a result, it is always better to put the content of your message into the answer, rather than linking out to a third party resource.